# material ui DataDrid pagination styling

Tags: material-ui

DataGrid component provides pagination by corresponding prop, which accepts true | undefined (according to source).
While pagination component itself has some props to change it's appearance, seems like there's no way of passing any of those to DataGrid's inner pagination?

At this point it seems that if you want to use custom styled pagination you need to use DataGrid and Pagination separately.

Anyone knows anything about this?

Answer (score 0):

Oops,  it  was  right  here  -  https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/rendering/